# How can i update one row usign two keys in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-update

I have a need to update a table like this :

`UPDATE table SET column = value WHERE first_id = 1 AND second_id = 2`

Is it possible to do this in Laravel using eloquent model? If it is how can i do this?

I was trying with :

```
$object = Model::where('first_id' , 1)->where('second_id' , 2)->get();

$object->column = $value

$object->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it. Here is how you can do it.

```
Model::where('first_id', 1)
      ->where('second_id', 2)
      ->update(['column' => 'yourValue']);
```

Comment: That one worked for me thankyou very much

Comment: @AgustinCastillo If this answer worked for you please mark it as accepted

Comment: @AgustinCastillo kindly mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first post here, didnt know that i was suposed to accept the answer, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a collection. You can update the column of each of those collection. You can only get the first one collection using first.

```
foreach($object as $obj){
   $obj->column = $value;
   $obj->save();
}
```

Or

```
$object = Model::where('first_id' , 1)->where('second_id' , 2)->first();


$obect->column =$value;
$object->save();
```

Comment: Yeah, but this example generates the sql UPDATE model SET column = value WHERE id = N.

Comment: how ? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: It´s like that : i needed to generate the query 
```UPDATE table SET column = value where first_id = X AND second_id = Y```.

Your suggestion generates : 
```UPDATE table SET column = value WHERE first_id = X```

Comment: I think you are getting this wrong. By the way,  I hope my answer will solve your problem